# Web Service thru Spring boot

Tags: javascript, web-services, spring-boot

I am referring someone code and not getting what exactly is the meaning of the below code as its throwing error when they are calling like sdServices.topup(null, null, null, topupRequest)

```js
  @WebMethod(operationName = "Topup")
    @WebResult(name = "topupResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.utiba.com/xml/ns/sdp/soap/service/v3", partName = "TopupResponse")
    public StandardResponse topup(
        @WebParam(partName = "ClientId", name = "clientId", targetNamespace = "http://www.utiba.com/xml/ns/sdp/soap/service/v3", header = true)
        java.lang.String clientId,
        @WebParam(partName = "TerminalId", name = "terminalId", targetNamespace = "http://www.utiba.com/xml/ns/sdp/soap/service/v3", header = true)
        java.lang.String terminalId,
        @WebParam(partName = "CardData", name = "cardData", targetNamespace = "http://www.amdocs.com/xml/ns/card/soap/v1", header = true)
        com.amdocs.xml.ns.card.soap.v1.CardData cardData,
        @WebParam(partName = "TopupRequest", name = "topupRequest", targetNamespace = "http://www.utiba.com/xml/ns/sdp/soap/service/v3")
        TopupRequest topupRequest
    ) throws SDPValidationFault_Exception, SDPFault_Exception;
```

Comment: "_its throwing error_" You should tell us what the error is, what research you did on that error, and what your exact confusion is with what you found.

Comment: Sorry for that..Its throwing com.utiba.xml.ns.sdp.soap.service.v3.SDPFault_Exception:Access Denied